# Change dinamically created elements of template by another on button click Angular 2

Tags: angular, templates

Got the next template:

```
<table class="table table-sm" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <td class="central">
      <p>{{category.categoryName}}</p>
      <!--<input class="form-control" value="{{category.categoryName}}">-->
    </td>

    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
    <!--<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Done</button></td>-->
    <!--<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Cancel</button></td>-->
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With *ngFor directive I dinamically create the table in first column of which there is a name of some category (every has also categoryId field), second column has Edit buttons, third - Delete buttons.

I'd like to have the next functionality: when user clicks Edit button p-element with category name in its line need to be replaced by Input element with value of category name, also Edit and Delete buttons need to be replaced with Done and Cancel buttons. Changes  only in the line with clicked Edit button.

Got the next model for categories:

```
export class Category {
 constructor(
   public categoryId: number,
   public categoryName: string
){}
}
```

here is a part of component file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Category} from "./models/category";
import {CategoryService} from "./category.service";

@Component({
 selector: 'my-categories',
 templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit{

categories: Category[];

constructor (private categoryService: CategoryService) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.getCategories();
}
...
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: I thought about adding all elements to the DOM, and some of them hide with ng-styles. But have no idea how can I get on button click some certain elements and change styles to show them and then get some couple of elements to hide them/

Comment: Start out simple - get it working for one row with static data

Comment: Aluan Haddad, you know, I've found many examples exactly for one row imlementation, but they will not work in my case because there is needless to make dinamically some specific IDs or variables that contain the hide-show state for Only One Row

Comment: I'm still not seeing any examples of things you have tried to do. Update your question please.

Comment: Could you give me an idea in what way do I need to go?

Comment: What you have asked is far too broad.

Comment: If I had a bug in my code I've made everything by myself without your help... I asked this question because got no ideas how to make this after 2 days of searching them....

Comment: I need to see code. Your attempted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the decision:
At first I've added boolean property "visibility" to Category class:

```
export class Category {
  constructor(
    public categoryId: number,
    public categoryName: string,
    public visibility: boolean = true
  ){}
}
```

Then I've added [hidden] properties to all DOM elements of template that I need to hide/show in accordance with Edit-Cancel buttons click. The values of this properties were initially set as a value of visibility property (true) of certain Category for initially shown elements and !visibility (as false) for initially hidden elements. As the result of click events for Edit-Cancel buttons I've made changing visibility to the inverse value:

```
<table class="table table-sm" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <td class="central">
      <p [hidden]="category.visibility">{{category.categoryName}}</p>
      <input [hidden]="!category.visibility" class="form-control" value="{{category.categoryName}}">
    </td>

    <td><button [hidden]="category.visibility" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" (click)="category.visibility = !category.visibility">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button [hidden]="category.visibility" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button></td>
    <td><button [hidden]="!category.visibility" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Done</button></td>
    <td><button [hidden]="!category.visibility" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="category.visibility = !category.visibility">Cancel</button></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```